# Google Chart in div with overflow-x: scroll results in large scroll area

Tags: css, google-visualization

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beams/5Lrfzv0f/) here.

I have multiple Google Charts that I wrap in a div container with `overflow-x: scroll` so that on smaller screens users can scroll to see the full chart.

However, the scroll area becomes very large (see JSFiddle) with a lot of white space. I have tried setting the width of the actual chart div (chart in this example) to no avail.

Edit:

Here's some code, the div `charts` contains the Google charts.

```
<div id="charts">
<div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#charts {
direction: rtl;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? The scroll spacing seems to me to look okay on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Latest version of Chrome. Here's a [screen shot](http://imgur.com/Uh0bmo1) of what I see. If I scroll to the left, there's a large area of nothing.

Comment: Very interesting, and different from what I'm seeing on the latest of Chrome. Can you make sure that none of your extensions are set to run in incognito mode, then go into incognito mode and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Seeing the same thing in incognito. I see the same thing on my Blackberry phone. Google'd "direction rtl long scrollbar" and found similar issues.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not seeing the scrollbar issue on my Android phone either. I wonder if it has to do with language settings somehow? In any case I'm going to star this question, because I'm very curious to see if anyone comes up with a solution.

Comment: I think it's my fault, I don't think the JSFiddle saved properly. From just playing around with it now, I don't think the issue is to do with Google Visualization, its the `direction: rtl` and `overflow-x: scroll;` that's causes the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. No, a link to an MCVE does not count. For debuggong questions to be on-topic on Stack Overflow,  you gotta have an MCVE *in* the question.

Answer (score 1):

`#chart` has a div element grandchild for holding tabular chart data with `position: absolute; left: -10000px;` on it that's creating the white space. Normally this wouldn't matter and the graph uses the property to hide the element off screen but `direction: rtl` changes the box model orientation.

```
#chart div div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or target the element and switch `left` to `right`:

```
[aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart."] {
    left: auto !important;
    right: -10000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did some further reading and it appears that this is a known issue / bug (see [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/03/the-curious-case-of-the-giant-scrollbar/))

Upon inspecting the elements, there is a hidden child `div dir="ltr"` property. I added the following to my CSS:

```
div[dir="ltr"] {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And the issue is gone. When viewing the chart on a large enough display, the horizontal scrolls bars disappear, however, on a smaller display, the scroll bars appear but are limited to the width of the chart.

Comment: You are targeting an arbitrary selector. My answer provides the cause, your selector is simply targeting a child div and preventing overflow. An element with `left: -10000px` (created by the Google chart) normally wouldn't have the effect because it is off to the left, but with `direction: rtl` it does since you changed the box model orientation.